# How to prevent blur on a textarea when a sound is played

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm creating an HTML-based chat. In this chat when you receive a new message a sound is being played using this code:

```
$('#sound-root').html('<embed src="'+soundfile+'" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" />');
```

The problem is, that in some browsers when you receive a message while typing a blur() event is being fired from the textarea and you should click on the textarea again to continue typing. Is there any workaround for that?

**PS:**

- **#sound-root** is an invisible element, used to play sounds only.
- **#textChat** is the id of the textarea.
- **#textChat** should be able to blur.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the blur happening on your textarea (if you don't need it at all)

```
$('#textChat').blur(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

If you need the blur event then set a variable when playing a sound to true and in this blur function you prevent it to happening only when the sound is playing.

Comment: **#sound-root** is an invisible element, used to play sounds only. 
**#textChat** is the id of the textarea.
**#textChat** should be able to blur.